# List normal wordpress categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

Hello I have dropdown with custom categories, here is link script that works for custom categories.

```
 var categories = [
        {foreach $categories as $category}
            { value: {$category->term_id}, label: {$category->name} }{if !($iterator->last)},{/if}
        {/foreach}
        ];
```

But I want to use normal categories in this dropdown, how I can change this script to show only normal categories ?

Here is my function file if needed http://jsfiddle.net/ELVFV/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
...
'taxonomy' => 'ait-dir-item-location',
...
```

You'll use

```
...
'taxonomy' => 'category',
...
```

To get categories (custom or default) you can use get_terms function. Here is an example:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category' );
foreach ( $categories as $category ){
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to make it works :( here is full script - can you help me please ? http://jsfiddle.net/jsLYk/

Comment: You are trying to setup an autocomplete function, don't you? If so, try autocomplete plugins already available: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/autocomplete

Comment: No, I just want drop down menu with normal categories and no custom categories